# Tenho muitos INNER JOIN na query, tem como minimizar?

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma consulta em um banco de dados que utiliza vários `INNER JOIN` e percebo que em alguns momentos o sistema fica lento nesta requisição, tem como reduzi-lá?

> Abaixo segue explicação de minha estrutura

- Tabela clientes com todos os dados endereço, nome e documentos;
- Tabela pedido de compra que contém os itens, qtdade e valor;
- Tabela produto que contém as caracteristicas, qtdade em estoque;
- Tabela fornecedores que contém todos os dados do fornecedor.

A Tabela pedido contém `id do produto`, `id do cliente`, e a tabela produto contém `o id do fornecedor`.

> Abaixo segue minha consulta sql em questão, a qual gostaria de saber como posso melhora-lá, ou se dessa forma ela já está correta.

```
SELECT ped_oc.id_pedido as pedido, tbl_clientes.Nome as cliente, tbl_usuarios.Nome as vendedor, fin_fornecedores.NomeFantasia as fornecedor, COUNT(fin_fornecedores.Id) as qtde, ped_oc.data_atualizacao as data 
FROM ped_oc
INNER JOIN tbl_aux_orcamento ON ped_oc.id_orcamento = tbl_aux_orcamento.Id
INNER JOIN tbl_clientes ON tbl_aux_orcamento.Id_cliente = tbl_clientes.Id
INNER JOIN tbl_usuarios ON tbl_aux_orcamento.Id_vendedor = tbl_usuarios.id
INNER JOIN tbl_produtos ON ped_oc.id_modelo = tbl_produtos.Id
INNER JOIN fin_fornecedores ON tbl_produtos.Id_Fornecedor = fin_fornecedores.Id
INNER JOIN ped_pedido ON ped_oc.id_pedido = ped_pedido.id_pedido
INNER JOIN tbl_orcamentos ON tbl_aux_orcamento.Id = tbl_orcamentos.Id_tbl_aux_orcamento
WHERE ped_pedido.status_oc = '1'
AND tbl_orcamentos.status = '1'
AND ped_pedido.id_pedido =  ped_oc.id_pedido
GROUP BY fin_fornecedores.NomeFantasia
```

Answer (score 0):

Não possuo conhecimento em otimização de queries, porém creio que uma maneira de otimizar é com a utilização de [índices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql). Verifique quais índices e se há algum que existe em suas tabelas, com exceção da chave primária (para verificar os comandos no mysql, clique [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table)). Feito isso, tente executar o select utilizando a palavra reservada [EXPLAIN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20038/how-can-i-tell-if-an-index-is-being-used-to-sort-in-mysql). Assim, mostrará o(s) índice(s) que está(ão) sendo utilizado(s). Desta forma, você poderá agir mediante a estas informações, criando um novo índice ou modificando-os de acordo com os relacionamentos existentes.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: estou tentando entender mas está confuso pra mim o uso de indices.